# Avoid deleting entire input value on backspace

Tags: javascript, input, backspace

I have an input field which is deleting all the words its contains when I'm pressing backspace key.

I tried to implement a small code to delete the words letter by letter but I'm getting an error: `selectInput.substring is not a function`.

```
let selectInput = document.querySelector('#searchedWord');

selectInput.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
const key = e.key;
 if (key === "Backspace") {
   selectInput.value = selectInput.substring(0, selectInput.length -1);
   // other code to be exectuded below
 }
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: First of all document.querySelector('#searchedWord); <<--- After searchedWord<- a ' hyphen is missing. Is this a write-down error when creating the post or is this your error already?

Comment: It's a write-down error, sorry. I corrected it

Comment: selectInput.substring(0, selectInput.length -1); is this meant to get value of your input?

Answer (score 2):

"selectInput" is NOT a string in your context its a DOM-object (or DOM-tree [=array] if multiple elements have been found but since you used an ID "#"searchedWord we should be fine here)

you must access ".value" attribute

Try:

```
selectInput.value = selectInput.value.substring(0, selectInput.length -1)
```

You basically already did it right where you assigned it into. :D

Comment: Thanks! I must pay bigger attention